# Stop Logstash agent on inactivity?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The central log server I'm working on uses two Logstash agents, each running in its own `screen`:

- a `shipper` to collect logs from front servers
- an `indexer` to send the logs into Elasticsearch

Sometimes, it can be useful to re-import some logs (on failure, to re-format the logs etc...). For this purpose, I execute a third agent called `importer` whose job is to re-import old logs.

The problem I'm facing is that I have to monitor the re-import processus until it's completely done and hence becomes killable.

So, I would like to know if there's some kind of option able to stop an agent on idleness.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with the `exec` input. (http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/exec). I'm thinking something like `cat /some/reload/file; sleep 30; kill $LS_PID` not quite sure on how you'd get `$LS_PID` assigned though.